# How to use awk to print all fields excluding a specific field?

Tags: linux, vim

I have a file of 100000 rows separated by ^M. Following are the first 4 rows. I want to remove 35=[etc] from every even row in the file of 100K rows

```
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000001, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000001, 11=000001, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604088, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127162,  37=500001000001,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=7B7AD380360E5C66,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000002, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000002, 11=000002, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604286, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127328,  37=500001000002,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=F55C5F27C8A91F31,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000003, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000003, 11=000003, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604997, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127295,  37=500001000003,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=CC3803D589D05384,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000004, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000004, 11=000004, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100605333, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127558,  37=500001000004,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=D9FB6238A83D8FDD,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
```

The output should be like

```
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000001, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000001, 11=000001, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604088, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127162,  37=500001000001,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=7B7AD380360E5C66,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000002, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000002, 11=000002, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604286, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 37=500001000002,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=F55C5F27C8A91F31,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000003, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000003, 11=000003, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100604997, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 35=2302127295,  37=500001000003,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=CC3803D589D05384,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
{1=0200, 62=01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001000004, 63=1000000000000000000000000002, 38=000004, 11=000004, 12=125216, 13=0213, 15=0213, 18=6011, 19=840, 2=4511230100605333, 22=9000, 25=00, 3=010000, 32=12345678901, 37=500001000004,  4=000000000300, 41=123ac130, 42=USA STORE000001, 43=SAFEWAY STORE #970       SAN MATEO    US, 49=0840, 52=D9FB6238A83D8FDD,  59=0600094044, 60=123456789000, 7=1103145214}^M
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Also your expected output is not clear, so please post logic(how to get sample output) along with sample expected output with CODE TAGS in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the `g` command in vim:

```
:g/35=[0-9]*, */ if getcurpos()[1] % 2 == 0 | s///g | endif
```

Basically what we do is:

1. The `g` command searches for every line that has a match for the regex `35=[0-9]*, *` and then executes the commands following it (in this case the `if` statement).
2. Check if the cursor position is even with `if getcurpos()[1] % 2 == 0`.
3. If it is even, replace with an empty string `s///g`.

More on the power of the `g` command here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g

Comment: But I want to  replace it not to all rows but just to even rows. It will do to all rows

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that one! Edited my answer and it should work as specified now ;)

Comment: Thanks @sander it worked. Can you please elaborate parts of command? and what its doing actually?

Comment: Done! Basically it works like this: `:g/pattern/cmd` where the `cmd` gets executed on each line that matches the `pattern`.

Comment: To be clear: I updated my original answer to explain the `g` command.

Comment: I didnt get one thing, that what [1] is doing getcurpos()?

Comment: The `getcurpos` function returns an array of length 5 that defines the current position of the cursor. The second element in this array is the line number. More on `getcurpos` here: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/ve7bgff5hg-the-five-values-that-define-cursor-position-in-vim

Comment: No problem, have a nice one! Don't forget to accept this answer as the answer to your question, that would make my day ;)

Comment: yeah I am going to accept. By the way if my element field is greater than 10 digits e.g on 52=[etc] field, what would be the change?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Do you mean that the `[etc]` in your example is longer than 10 digits? In that case nothing, the regex will find everything where `[etc]` is any number of numerical digits.

Comment: Actually that comment didnt work on linux. It worked perfectly fine on Solaris

Comment: Are you using it inside of vim?

Comment: No. Actually it worked on Vim but I need it for Linux

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if 62=[digits] or if 11=[digits] are reliable row counters. But if they are, maybe consider something like this in Vim?

```
g/\v11\=\d+[0248],/s/\v, 35\=\d{10}//
```

This filters on the 11=[digits] for even numbers

```
g/\v62\=\d+[0248],/s/\v, 35\=\d{10}//
```

Filters on the 62=[digits] for even numbers